# Flutter - ListTile unnecessary tab space

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

[image]

There are unnecessary spaces in the code part of all my ListTiles as in the image, what is the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: You can just remove the new line, no?

Comment: Which IDE are you are using

Comment: Shift+Alt+F will format your code and remove unneccessary whitespace in VS Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line controlled by `Dart:Line Length` in vs-code. You can change it from setting,

[image]

Or on setting JSON

[image]